# Convert all text in a file to uppercase using sed and interested to use range operator

Tags: sed

I am trying to : Convert all text in a file to uppercase using sed and interested to use range operator. can some one please help me here.

content of Sample.text: unix is great os. unix is opensource. unix is free os. learn operating system. Unix Linux which one you choose.

Thanks in Advance again

Answer (score 2):

There are *many* ways to do this. Here is another. You can figure out more ways.

```
  echo "unix is great os." | tr [a-z] [A-Z]
  UNIX IS GREAT OS.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/.*/\U&/' Sample.text
```

Comment: I am interested to use range operator here; like [a-z]. Please give me a solution using range operator.

Comment: @VenkataNagaAmarBoggavarapu you can simply use like: `sed y/def/DEF/`